# How to check for a key in softlayer datatypes

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have the following piece of code

```
import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/session"
        "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/services"
        "github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/filter"
        "encoding/json"
        "strconv"
)

func main() {
    sess := session.New("XX", "XX")
    accountService := services.GetAccountService(sess)
    var volid int = 39283541
    result, err :=  accountService.Mask("id,snapshoCapacityGb").Filter(filter.Path("networkStorage.id").Eq(volid).Build()).GetNetworkStorage()
    .....

}
```

Here the `result` is of type `[]datatypes.Network_Storage` For some volids the `snapshoCapacityGb` key is not there in the response at all. I only have `id`.

for eg:

```
    {
       "id": 49282191
    }
```

I want to have some custom logic if `snapshoCapacityGb` is not there in the result. How can check for that key in the object of type `datatypes.Network_Storage` ?

I get the follwowing error if `snapshoCapacityGb` is not there in the result an  I try to use it

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x752f99]

goroutine 1 [running]:
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out:

```
 if result[0].SnapshotCapacityGb == nil {
            fmt.Println("no SnapshotCapacityGb ")
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters if you want to retrieve all those storage devices which have snapshot space in the account

```
objectFilter={"networkStorage":{"snapshotCapacityGb":{"operation":"not null"}}}
```

Try with the following REST call:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[id,capacityGb,snapshotCapacityGb,storageType]&objectFilter={"networkStorage":{"snapshotCapacityGb":{"operation":"not null"}}}
```